Angular Ngrx-Forms Async Pipe Could not be found error
I want to manage the state of my form using ngrx-forms library;
so following docs:
https://ngrx-forms.readthedocs.io/en/master/
i have a reducer:
import { Action, createReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import {
  FormGroupState,
  createFormGroupState,
  formGroupReducer,
  onNgrxForms,
} from 'ngrx-forms';
import { Gender } from '../../core/enums/gender_enum';

// 1. Definicja modelu danych formularza
export interface PatientFormValue {
  name: string;
  last_name: string;
  age: number;
  gender: Gender;
}
// 2. Początkowy stan formularza
const FORM_ID = 'PatientFormValue';
const initialFormState = createFormGroupState<PatientFormValue>(FORM_ID, {
  name: '',
  last_name: '',
  age: 0,
  gender: Gender.nie_podawać,
});

// 3. Definicja stanu aplikacji
export interface PatientDataState {
  someOtherField: string;
  myForm: FormGroupState<PatientFormValue>;
}

const initialState: PatientDataState = {
  someOtherField: '',
  myForm: initialFormState,
};

// 4. Reducer zwiazany a formularzem
export function patientFormReducer(
  state = initialState,
  action: Action,
): PatientDataState {
  const myForm = formGroupReducer(state.myForm, action);
  if (myForm !== state.myForm) {
    state = { ...state, myForm };
  }
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'some action type':
      return state;
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

export function reducer(state: PatientDataState | undefined, action: Action) {
  return patientFormReducer(state, action);
}


then the app html:
<ng-container *ngIf="formState$ | async as formState">
  <form novalidate [ngrxFormState]="formState">
    <input
      type="text"
      [ngrxFormControlState]="formState.controls.someTextInput"
    />

    <input
      type="checkbox"
      [ngrxFormControlState]="formState.controls.someCheckbox"
    />

    <input
      type="number"
      [ngrxFormControlState]="formState.controls.nested.controls.someNumber"
    />
  </form>
</ng-container>

and compontent.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OverviewNavComponent } from '../overview-nav/overview-nav.component';
import { RouterLink, Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
// store
import { Store, StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { FormGroupState, NgrxFormsModule, setValue } from 'ngrx-forms';
// icons
import { NgIconComponent, provideIcons } from '@ng-icons/core';
import {
  bootstrapArrowRightCircleFill,
  bootstrapArrowLeftCircleFill,
} from '@ng-icons/bootstrap-icons';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {
  PatientDataState,
  PatientFormValue,
} from '../../../../store/patient-store/patients.reducer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-patients-data',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    NgIconComponent,
    OverviewNavComponent,
    RouterLink,
    NgrxFormsModule,
    StoreModule,
  ],
  templateUrl: './patients-data.component.html',
  styleUrl: './patients-data.component.css',
  viewProviders: [
    provideIcons({
      bootstrapArrowRightCircleFill,
      bootstrapArrowLeftCircleFill,
    }),
  ],
})
export class PatientsDataComponent {
  formState$: Observable<FormGroupState<PatientFormValue>>;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private store: Store<PatientDataState>,
  ) {
    this.formState$ = store.select((s) => s.myForm);
  }

  // updateFormValue(newValue: PatientFormValue) {
  //   this.store.dispatch(setValue({ value: newValue }));
  // }
}


For now, when i access the component i get error console:
 The pipe 'async' could not be found

so i add import:
CommonModule 

and then i get:
Property 'someTextInput' does not exist on type 'FormGroupControls<PatientFormValue>'.

Another problem is using
<ng-container *ngIf="formState$ | async as formState">

as I am using Angular17 and i am not sure if cant switch to:
@if(formState$ | async as formState){ }

When i import the CommonModule i get multiple errors but i fix the pipe problem. Without CommonModule i get pipe problem but the form seems to work.
How to save and retrive data to ngrx Store using ngrx forms and Angular 17? How to fix async pipe problem?
I tried adding and removing CommonModule and rewriting the @if statement. Also, i dont really understand how to manipulate data- change the data on change() using this library.
edit:
after adding CommonModule i have now:
inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer


You're using standalone component, so don't import whole modules (CommonModule). You can simply import AsyncPipe from '@angular/common'

Maybe you should use a better IDE, because with a good one, "| async" in html file would have been underlined saying you're missing the import and suggesting to add the import. It helps to develop!

Async pipe is something that needs to be imported to be used.
When working with standalone components you can see standalone: true set on the component decorator.
You can either import AsyncPipe or CommonModule (contains many directives and pipes, e.g. NgIf, CurrencyPipe, NgFor) from '@angular/common'.
...
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
...

...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-patients-data',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule, // <- changed here!
    NgIconComponent,
    OverviewNavComponent,
    RouterLink,
    NgrxFormsModule,
    StoreModule,
  ],
...

